# Calculating image size on different PPI display

Tags: javascript, c#, math, graphics, 2d

If I have an image what have 30mm height on display with 72ppi, how can I calculate its size on different displays with different ppt that results same height (30mm)?

Answer (score 0):

The formula you seek is:

```
var resolution = desiredSize * density;
```

Remember that desired size is expressed in inches, so you must convert the milimeters to inches:

```
var inches = milimeters * 0.0393701;
```

Per example, if you have a 150ppi monitor, for 30mm the resolution would be:

```
var resolution = 30 * 0.0393701 * 150; // -> 177px
```